# how to predict a masked word in a given sentence

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

FitBERT is an useful package , but I have a small doubt on BERT development for masked word prediction as below: I trained a bert model with custom corpus using Google's Scripts like `create_pretraining_data.py`, `run_pretraining.py`, `extract_features.py` etc..as a result I got vocab file, `.tfrecord` file, `.json` file and check point files.

Now how to use those file for your package to predict a masked word in a given sentence??

Answer (score 0):

From the tensorflow documentation:

> A TFRecord file stores your data as a sequence of binary strings. This means you need to specify the structure of your data before you write it to the file. Tensorflow provides two components for this purpose: tf.train.Example and tf.train.SequenceExample. You have to store each sample of your data in one of these structures, then serialize it and use a tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter to write it to disk.

This [document](https://medium.com/mostly-ai/tensorflow-records-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them-c46bc4bbb564) along with the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord) explain quite well how to use those file types.

While instead to use FitBERT directly through the library you can follow the examples you find on the project's [github](https://github.com/Qordobacode/fitbert).